# exec limited to 4000 characters?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, exec

trying to execute this script gives only the first select as a result

```
declare @sp nvarchar(max)
select @sp = concat(N'select 1 ', replicate('-', 5000), char(13) + char(10), N'select 2')
exec (@sp)
```

but when I lower hyphens to 1000, I get also the second select
How can I overcome this limit?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is with the `CONCAT`.

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql#remarks), the return type depends on the type of the parameters. With a mixture of short `nvarchar` and `varchar` literal strings, your `CONCAT` will return `nvarchar` with some maximum length less than or equal to 4000.

A rewrite to use a `max` data type and consistent data types otherwise functions as you desire:

```
DECLARE @sp nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sp = CONCAT
    (
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'select 1 '), 
        REPLICATE(N'-', 5000), 
        NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10), 
        N'select 2'
    );

EXECUTE (@sp);
```

[Online db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c816e06c734450098817940776472906)